# One to one chat in socket io

Tags: socket.io

Need help with socketio one to one chat.
I have read tons of example stating to create a room for private chat.
The example one I always get will be something like this :

```js
io.on('connection', socket => {
    //Get the chatID of the user and join in a room of the same chatID
    chatID = socket.handshake.query.chatID
    socket.join(chatID)

    //Leave the room if the user closes the socket
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.leave(chatID)
    })

    //Send message to only a particular user
    socket.on('send_message', message => {
        receiverChatID = message.receiverChatID
        senderChatID = message.senderChatID
        content = message.content

        //Send message to only that particular room
        socket.in(receiverChatID).emit('receive_message', {
            'content': content,
            'senderChatID': senderChatID,
            'receiverChatID':receiverChatID,
        })
    })
});
```

But I can't get my head around: as in this example for the room "receiverChatID", all user who are currently sending message to the same receiver [say user2] will receive a broadcast of the messages other user are sending.

For example user 1 and user 2 are having private chat conversation. The chat room id is "user2".
Now user3 sends message to user 2, again the room name will be "user2" and hence when a broadcast will be done, both user 3 and user 1 will receive messages , even though they should be private individually.

One way will be to create a unique chat-room-id between two users, and maintain in it some data store.If that is the way to do it, then how to create unique chat room id, specifically, when user join and leave and re-join save room.
And query this unqique room for two users, whenever they join in ?

Say I create a map : {roomid1: MD5["user1","user2"]}.
Now how do you decide the order of user1 and user 2 [alphabetical I guess], so for two pairs of users one unique room id is created ?

How do you solve this problems for one to one chat ?